# org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["values"] is not a JSONArray."

Tags: java, json

This my json array.

```
[
  {
    "type":"select",
    "label":"Select",
    "className":"form-control",
    "name":"select-1497355331262",
    "values":[
              {
                "label":"Option 1", 
                "value":"option-1",
                "selected":true
               }, 
             {
              "label":"Option 2",
              "value":"option-2"
             },
            {
              "label":"Option 3", 
              "value":"option-3"
            }
         ]
       }
]
```

My Appraoch :

```
JSONArray js = null;
            try {
                js = new JSONArray(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONObject obj = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    obj = js.getJSONObject(i);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    type = obj.getString("type");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    type = null;
                }

                System.out.println("Type : " + type);


                try {
                    JSONArray jContent = obj.getJSONArray("values");
                    System.out.println(jContent.toString());
                    for (int iterate = 0; iterate < jContent.length(); iterate++) {
                        JSONObject inner = jContent.getJSONObject(iterate);
                        String inner_label = (String) inner.get("label");

                        System.out.println(inner_label);

                        String val = (String) inner.get("value");
                        boolean sel;
                        try {
                            sel = (boolean) inner.get("selected");

                        } catch (JSONException j) {
                            sel = false;
                        }
                        System.out.print(inner_label);
                        System.out.print(" " + val);
                        System.out.println(" " + sel);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("There is some error");
                }

                try {
                    label = obj.getString("label");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    access = obj.getBoolean("access");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    access = false;
                }

                try {
                    role = obj.getString("role");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    role = null;
                }

                try {
                    subtype = obj.getString("subtype");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    subtype = null;
                }

                try {
                    maxlength = obj.getString("maxlength");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    maxlength = null;
                }

                try {
                    name = obj.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    name = null;
                }

                try {
                    description = obj.getString("description");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    description = null;
                }

                try {
                    classname = obj.getString("className");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    classname = null;
                }

                try {
                    placeholder = obj.getString("placeholder");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    placeholder = null;
                }

                try {
                    value = obj.getString("value");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    value = null;
                }

                try {
                    required = obj.getBoolean("required");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    required = false;
                }
                try {
                    toggle = obj.getBoolean("toggle");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    toggle = false;
                }
                try {
                    inline = obj.getBoolean("inline");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    inline = false;
                }
                try {
                    enableother = obj.getBoolean("other");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    enableother = false;
                }
                try {
                    multipleFiles = obj.getBoolean("multiple");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    multipleFiles = false;
                }
                try {
                    style = obj.getString("style");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    style = null;
                }
                try {
                    min = obj.getString("min");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    min = null;
                }
                try {
                    max = obj.getString("max");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    max = null;
                }
                try {
                    step = obj.getString("step");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    step = null;
                }
                try {
                    rows = obj.getString("rows");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    rows = null;
                }
```

I am able to get all other objects values I am unable to read the values array. I have written the code for it but its directly going to the catch block printing the error message "There is some error". Thnaks  for the help.

Comment: Why is your catch block so weak? Instead of printing "there is some error", why not print the stack trace as you do elsewhere, `e.printStackTrace();`? This will give you much more useful information about the error.

Comment: Also, why so many small try/catch blocks?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels hey check the error "org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["values"] is not a JSONArray."

Comment: Have you considered using a library like Jackson to map JSON to Java Objects? Just create a POJO,  and deserialize the JSON String with a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...Values was not an array it was an object....So here's what I did. It worked.

```
 try {

                String j2 = obj.getString("values");
                JSONArray jContent = new JSONArray(j2);
                                    for (int iterate = 0; iterate < jContent.length(); iterate++) {
                        JSONObject inner = jContent.getJSONObject(iterate);
                        String inner_label = (String) inner.get("label");

                        System.out.println(inner_label);

                        String val = (String) inner.get("value");
                        boolean sel;
                        try {
                            sel = (boolean) inner.get("selected");

                        } catch (JSONException j) {
                            sel = false;
                        }
                        System.out.print(inner_label);
                        System.out.print(" " + val);
                        System.out.println(" " + sel);

                    }
```