# Getting JSONArray result in "org.json.JSONException: Value{data}"

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am using Volley to request unsplash API but when  I try requesting it as `JsonObjectRequest` it doesn't give me any errors but I know that is a wrong approach because the data I am receiving is `JSONArray`

MY APPROACH

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if(response!=null){
                    // Process the JSON
                        try{
                            // Loop through the array elements
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject js = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d("TESTING",js.getString("id"));
                            }
                        p.dismiss();
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }}
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Log.d("TESTING",error.getMessage());
                }
            });
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

LOG 
Since the JSONArray is too big to post here this is the formate

```
D/TESTING: org.json.JSONException: Value {"total": 44760,
"total_pages": 4476,
"results":[{JSONObjects}]}
```

If you wish to view the JSONArray here is the link "`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=wood&client_id=ACESS_KEY_REQUIRED`"

also I have viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521278/org-json-jsonexception-jsonobjectvalues-is-not-a-jsonarray) question but that is totally different

You can request a key simply by making an account [here](https://unsplash.com/developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create jsonObject first. You requested for `JSONArray` but your server response as `JSONObject`. Try `StringRequest` for getting the `JSONObject`.

**Try this:**

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        // Loop through the array elements
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.d("TESTING", js.getString("id"));
                        }
                        p.dismiss();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.d("TESTING",error.getMessage()); 
        }
    })
};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
Cannot resolve constructor 'JSONObject(org.json.JSONArray)'

Comment: It worked thank you soo much ! but in every object of result there are fields such as "id", "height" etc and "urls" now these urls are like :   "urls": {"raw":"data", "full":"data"......} Any idea how to get these fields of "raw" and "full"

Comment: I did it Thank You again for the time and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You are request for json object but request time you call jsonarrayrequest so JsonException is come

```
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       try {
           JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject js = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               Log.d("TESTING",js.getString("id"));
}
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
   }
});
```

Comment: It's not working Logcat: " E/Volley: [1] 8.onErrorResponse: Error: "

Comment: you have get method i post for Post method PLease change it as per my edit

Comment: Your answer is also using GET but I tried using POST, same error

Comment: please check your api

Comment: If my API was wrong why would I get a JSONArray in my Exception ?